# Assert on Future Dates in Symfony 2.7

Tags: php, symfony

How can I make a validation that will not let the user accepts future dates on Symfony Entities.

I have the following Assertion code in my Entity:

```
  /**
 * @var date
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="birthday", type="date")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your birthday.", groups={"Registration", "Profile", "AdminEdit"})
 * @Assert\LessThanOrEqual("+1 year Asia/Tokyo", message="Invalid date", groups={"Registration", "Profile", "AdminEdit"})
 * 
 */

private $birthday;
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should use `today` assertion because you can't predict anybody's birthdate.

Answer (score 0):

Your assertion seems correct, so the required errors should be thrown when Symfonies validator is run on it.

When you're creating a form and use `$form->isValid()`, this assertion is automatically checked.

You can also use symfonies validator to run the assertions without using forms. This can be done using this code:

```
// fetch the validator from the symfony container (assuming you're in a controller)
$validator = $this->get('validator');
// run it and return errors
$errors = $validator->validate($author);
```